# Get all text inside a tag in lxml

Tags: python, parsing, lxml

I'd like to write a code snippet that would grab all of the text inside the `<content>` tag, in lxml, in all three instances below, including the code tags. I've tried `tostring(getchildren())` but that would miss the text in between the tags. I didn't have very much luck searching the API for a relevant function. Could you help me out?

```html
<!--1-->
<content>
<div>Text inside tag</div>
</content>
#should return "<div>Text inside tag</div>

<!--2-->
<content>
Text with no tag
</content>
#should return "Text with no tag"


<!--3-->
<content>
Text outside tag <div>Text inside tag</div>
</content>
#should return "Text outside tag <div>Text inside tag</div>"
```

Comment: Thanks - I was trying to write an RSS feed parser and display everything inside the <content> tag, which includes HTML tags from the feed provider.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try:

```
def stringify_children(node):
    from lxml.etree import tostring
    from itertools import chain
    parts = ([node.text] +
            list(chain(*([c.text, tostring(c), c.tail] for c in node.getchildren()))) +
            [node.tail])
    # filter removes possible Nones in texts and tails
    return ''.join(filter(None, parts))
```

Example:

```
from lxml import etree
node = etree.fromstring("""<content>
Text outside tag <div>Text <em>inside</em> tag</div>
</content>""")
stringify_children(node)
```

Produces: `'\nText outside tag <div>Text <em>inside</em> tag</div>\n'`

Comment: You propably want this to be recursive, in case of e.g. `Text <em>outside</em> tag <div>Text <em>inside</em> tag</div>`.

Comment: @delnan. It is not needed, `tostring` already handles the recursive case. You've made me doubt so I tried it out on real code and updated the answer with an example. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @delnan. Ok, I think I've got you now... You were referring to the text and tails of children, right? Fixed the answer taking that into account.

Comment: Code is broken and produces duplicate content: 
>>> stringify_children(lxmlhtml.fromstring('A<div>B</div>C'))
'A<p>A</p>B<div>B</div>CC'

Comment: To fix the bug @hoju reported, add `with_tail=False` as a parameter to `tostring()`. So `tostring(c, with_tail=False)`. This will fix the problem with the tail text (`C`). For fixing the problem with the prefix text (`A`), this seems to be a bug in `tostring()` that adds the `<p>` tag, so it's not a bug in OP's code.

Comment: Second bug can be fixed by removing `c.text` from the `parts` list. I submitted a new answer with these bugs fixed.

Comment: Should add `tostring(c, encoding=str)` to be run on Python 3.

Answer (score 106):

Just use the `node.itertext()` method, as in:

```
 ''.join(node.itertext())
```

Comment: This works great, but strips out any tags that you might want.

Comment: Should the string not have a space in it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Private It depends on your specific needs. For instance I could have markup like `<word><pre>con</pre>gregate</word>` to indicate a prefix in a word. Let's say I want to extract the word without markup. If I use `.join` with a space, then I'd get `"con gregate"` whereas without a space I get `"congregate"`.

Comment: While the answer above was accepted, this is what I actually wanted.

Answer (score 92):

Does [text_content()](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#html-element-methods) do what you need?

Comment: text_content() removes all markup and the OP wants to keep the markup that is inside the tag.

Comment: @benselme why I use `text_content`, it says `AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'text_content'`

Comment: @roger `text_content()` is available only if your tree is HTML (i.e. if it was parsed with the methods in `lxml.html`).

Comment: @EdSummers Thanks a lot! This is useful while parsing a `<p>` tag. I was missing text (like nested links) while using `text()` in XPath, but your method worked for me!.

Comment: As Louis noted, this works only for trees parsed using `lxml.html`. Arthur Debert's solution with `itertext()` is universal.

Comment: To make it clearer, `text_content` is HTML Element method, `itertext` is Element method.

Answer (score 22):

A version of albertov 's [stringify-content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4624146/2230260) that solves the [bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624062/get-all-text-inside-a-tag-in-lxml/4624146#comment19772000_4624146) reported by hoju:

```
def stringify_children(node):
    from lxml.etree import tostring
    from itertools import chain
    return ''.join(
        chunk for chunk in chain(
            (node.text,),
            chain(*((tostring(child, with_tail=False), child.tail) for child in node.getchildren())),
            (node.tail,)) if chunk)
```

Answer (score 22):

The following snippet which uses python generators works perfectly and is very efficient.

`''.join(node.itertext()).strip()`

Comment: If the node is acquired from and indented text, depending on the parser it will usually have the indentation text, which itertext() will interweave in the normal text snippets. Depending on the actual setup, the following may be useful: `' '.join(node.itertext('span', 'b'))` - only use the text from `<span>` and `<b>` tags, discarding the tags with "\n     " from the indentation.

Answer (score 6):

Defining `stringify_children` this way may be less complicated:

```
from lxml import etree

def stringify_children(node):
    s = node.text
    if s is None:
        s = ''
    for child in node:
        s += etree.tostring(child, encoding='unicode')
    return s
```

or in one line

```
return (node.text if node.text is not None else '') + ''.join((etree.tostring(child, encoding='unicode') for child in node))
```

Rationale is the same as in [this answer](/a/16304543/1683555): leave the serialization of child nodes to lxml. The `tail` part of `node` in this case isn't interesting since it is "behind" the end tag. Note that the `encoding` argument may be changed according to one's needs.

Another possible solution is to serialize the node itself and afterwards, strip the start and end tag away:

```
def stringify_children(node):
    s = etree.tostring(node, encoding='unicode', with_tail=False)
    return s[s.index(node.tag) + 1 + len(node.tag): s.rindex(node.tag) - 2]
```

which is somewhat horrible. This code is correct only if `node` has no attributes, and I don't think anyone would want to use it even then.

Comment: `node.text if node.text is not None else ''` can be just `node.txt or ''`

Comment: Playing Lazarus a bit here (resurrection joke... not punny), but I've seen this post a number of times when I couldn't remember exactly what I did. Given node.text only returns the text not seen as part of the iterator (when iterating directly into a node, same as node.getChildren() I believe), it seems the solution could easily be simplified down from this to: `''.join([node.text or ''] + [etree.tostring(e) for e in node])`

Comment: This one actually works with python 3, whereas the most upvoted answer does not.

Answer (score 6):

One of the simplest code snippets, that actually worked for me and as per documentation at http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#using-xpath-to-find-text is

```
etree.tostring(html, method="text")
```

where etree is a node/tag whose complete text, you are trying to read. Behold that it doesn't get rid of script and style tags though.

Comment: strips the html tags

Answer (score 5):

```
import urllib2
from lxml import etree
url = 'some_url'
```

getting url

```
test = urllib2.urlopen(url)
page = test.read()
```

getting all html code within   including table tag

```
tree = etree.HTML(page)
```

xpath selector

```
table = tree.xpath("xpath_here")
res = etree.tostring(table)
```

res is the html code of table
this was doing job for me.

so you can extract the tags content with xpath_text() and tags including their content using tostring()

```
div = tree.xpath("//div")
div_res = etree.tostring(div)
```

```
text = tree.xpath_text("//content")
```

or text = tree.xpath("//content/text()")

```
div_3 = tree.xpath("//content")
div_3_res = etree.tostring(div_3).strip('<content>').rstrip('</')
```

this last line with strip method using is not nice, but it just works

Comment: For me, this works well enough and is admittedly much simpler. I know that I have a  <details></details> tag -- every time -- and I can strip it out

Comment: Has `xpath_text` already been removed from lxml? It says `AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'xpath_text'`

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick enhancement as the answer has been given. If you want to clean the inside text:

```
clean_string = ' '.join([n.strip() for n in node.itertext()]).strip()
```

Answer (score 2):

In response to @Richard's comment above, if you patch stringify_children to read:

```
 parts = ([node.text] +
--            list(chain(*([c.text, tostring(c), c.tail] for c in node.getchildren()))) +
++            list(chain(*([tostring(c)] for c in node.getchildren()))) +
           [node.tail])
```

it seems to avoid the duplication he refers to.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old question, but this is a common problem and I have a solution that seems simpler than the ones suggested so far:

```
def stringify_children(node):
    """Given a LXML tag, return contents as a string

       >>> html = "<p><strong>Sample sentence</strong> with tags.</p>"
       >>> node = lxml.html.fragment_fromstring(html)
       >>> extract_html_content(node)
       "<strong>Sample sentence</strong> with tags."
    """
    if node is None or (len(node) == 0 and not getattr(node, 'text', None)):
        return ""
    node.attrib.clear()
    opening_tag = len(node.tag) + 2
    closing_tag = -(len(node.tag) + 3)
    return lxml.html.tostring(node)[opening_tag:closing_tag]
```

Unlike some of the other answers to this question this solution preserves all of tags contained within it and attacks the problem from a different angle than the other working solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution. We can get content with a parent tag and then cut the parent tag from output.

```
import re
from lxml import etree

def _tostr_with_tags(parent_element, html_entities=False):
    RE_CUT = r'^<([\w-]+)>(.*)</([\w-]+)>$' 
    content_with_parent = etree.tostring(parent_element)    

    def _replace_html_entities(s):
        RE_ENTITY = r'&#(\d+);'

        def repl(m):
            return unichr(int(m.group(1)))

        replaced = re.sub(RE_ENTITY, repl, s, flags=re.MULTILINE|re.UNICODE)

        return replaced

    if not html_entities:
        content_with_parent = _replace_html_entities(content_with_parent)

    content_with_parent = content_with_parent.strip() # remove 'white' characters on margins

    start_tag, content_without_parent, end_tag = re.findall(RE_CUT, content_with_parent, flags=re.UNICODE|re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)[0]

    if start_tag != end_tag:
        raise Exception('Start tag does not match to end tag while getting content with tags.')

    return content_without_parent
```

`parent_element` must have `Element` type.

**Please note,** that if you want text content (not html entities in text) please leave `html_entities` parameter as False.

Comment: How do you use this function? Can you demonstrate that?

Comment: _tostr_with_tags(root_element_whose_inner_content_to_include)?

Answer (score 1):

lxml have a method for that:

```
node.text_content()
```

Comment: This answer does not add anything new. The same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/11963661/407651.

Comment: The lxml documentation also appears to be wrong: `AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'text_content'`

Comment: @mikerodent https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624062/get-all-text-inside-a-tag-in-lxml/11963661#comment50847722_11963661

Comment: @LukaBanfi Thanks. Also that's clever to have found out how to link to a comment: are you a wizard?

Answer (score -2):

If this is an a tag, you can try:

```
node.values()
```

Comment: This doesn't get the text inside the tag, it gets the attributes inside the tag.

Answer (score -2):

```
import re
from lxml import etree

node = etree.fromstring("""
<content>Text before inner tag
    <div>Text
        <em>inside</em>
        tag
    </div>
    Text after inner tag
</content>""")

print re.search("\A<[^<>]*>(.*)</[^<>]*>\Z", etree.tostring(node), re.DOTALL).group(1)
```