# Equivalent to InnerHTML when using lxml.html to parse HTML

Tags: python, parsing, lxml

I'm working on a script using lxml.html to parse web pages. I have done a fair bit of BeautifulSoup in my time but am now experimenting with lxml due to its speed.

I would like to know what the most sensible way in the library is to do the equivalent of Javascript's InnerHtml - that is, to retrieve or set the complete contents of a tag.

```html
<body>
<h1>A title</h1>
<p>Some text</p>
</body>
```

InnerHtml is therefore:

```html
<h1>A title</h1>
<p>Some text</p>
```

I can do it using hacks (converting to string/regexes etc) but I'm assuming that there is a correct way to do this using the library which I am missing due to unfamiliarity. Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Thanks to pobk for showing me the way on this so quickly and effectively. For anyone trying the same, here is what I ended up with:

```
from lxml import html
from cStringIO import StringIO
t = html.parse(StringIO(
"""<body>
<h1>A title</h1>
<p>Some text</p>
Untagged text
<p>
Unclosed p tag
</body>"""))
root = t.getroot()
body = root.body
print (element.text or '') + ''.join([html.tostring(child) for child in body.iterdescendants()])
```

Note that the lxml.html parser will fix up the unclosed tag, so beware if this is a problem.

Comment: You may consider using `encoding='unicode'` in html.tostring in order to get nice Unicode strings rather than a horrible byte soup Python hates.

Comment: this isn't quite right either; if `element.text` contains any metacharacters, they'll come out literally.  you **must** HTML-escape it yourself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the children of an ElementTree node using the getchildren() or iterdescendants() methods of the root node:

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> from cStringIO import StringIO
>>> t = etree.parse(StringIO("""<body>
... <h1>A title</h1>
... <p>Some text</p>
... </body>"""))
>>> root = t.getroot()
>>> for child in root.iterdescendants(),:
...  print etree.tostring(child)
...
<h1>A title</h1>

<p>Some text</p>
```

This can be shorthanded as follows:

```
print ''.join([etree.tostring(child) for child in root.iterdescendants()])
```

Comment: Note that you'll want to call .iterchildren() and not .iterdescendants() -- the latter will cause severe duplication of content, as .tostring() will descend itself.  For example, see the duplication of the 'two' and 'four' nodes: https://gist.github.com/1290412

Comment: Note that regardless of whether you use `iterchildren` or `iterdescendants`, both of these solutions are incorrect and will completely ignore text nodes contained by the parent element.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624062/get-all-text-inside-a-tag-in-lxml for a better answer.

Answer (score 16):

Sorry for bringing this up again, but I've been looking for a solution and yours contains a bug:

```html
<body>This text is ignored
<h1>Title</h1><p>Some text</p></body>
```

Text directly under the root element is ignored. I ended up doing this:

```
(body.text or '') +\
''.join([html.tostring(child) for child in body.iterchildren()])
```

Comment: Thanks lormus, you are correct - I have edited the answer above, good spot.

Comment: `body.text` should be escaped

Answer (score 4):

```
import lxml.etree as ET

     body = t.xpath("//body");
     for tag in body:
         h = html.fromstring( ET.tostring(tag[0]) ).xpath("//h1");
         p = html.fromstring(  ET.tostring(tag[1]) ).xpath("//p");             
         htext = h[0].text_content();
         ptext = h[0].text_content();
```

you can also use `.get('href')` for a tag and `.attrib` for attribute ,

here tag no is hardcoded but you can also do this dynamic

Comment: I need to remove tags like `<em>`, `<italic>` or `<a>`. This `test_content` saves my day.

Comment: Should be `ptext = p[0].text_content();` (If I could edit single char I'd also reduce the double space before `  ET.tostring(tag[1])` to a single.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Python 3 version:

```
from xml.sax import saxutils
from lxml import html

def inner_html(tree):
    """ Return inner HTML of lxml element """
    return (saxutils.escape(tree.text) if tree.text else '') + \
        ''.join([html.tostring(child, encoding=str) for child in tree.iterchildren()])
```

Note that this includes escaping of the initial text as recommended by [andreymal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123351/equivalent-to-innerhtml-when-using-lxml-html-to-parse-html/58862936#comment90193726_6396097) -- this is needed to avoid tag injection if you're working with sanitized HTML!

Answer (score 2):

I find none of the answers satisfying, some are even in Python 2. So I add a one-liner solution that produces innerHTML-like output and works with Python 3:

```py
from lxml import etree, html

# generate some HTML element node
node = html.fromstring("""<container>
Some random text <b>bold <i>italic</i> yeah</b> no yeah
<!-- comment blah blah -->  <img src='gaga.png' />
</container>""")

# compute inner HTML of element
innerHTML = "".join([
    str(c) if type(c)==etree._ElementUnicodeResult 
    else html.tostring(c, with_tail=False).decode() 
    for c in node.xpath("node()")
]).strip()
```

The result will be:

```py
'Some random text <b>bold <i>italic</i> yeah</b> no yeah\n<!-- comment blah blah -->  <img src="gaga.png">'
```

What it does: The xpath delivers all node children (text, elements, comments). The list comprehension produces a list of the text contents of the text nodes and HTML content of element nodes. Those are then joined into a single string. If you want to get rid of comments, use `*|text()` instead of `node()` for xpath.