# How to return result as HTML with HtmlXPathSelector (Scrapy)

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

How do I retrieve all the HTML contained inside a tag?

```
hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
element = hxs.select('//span[@class="title"]/')
```

Perhaps something like:

```
hxs.select('//span[@class="title"]/html()')
```

**EDIT:**
If I look at the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/selectors.html#xpathselectorlist-objects), I see only methods to return a new `XPathSelectorList`, or just the raw text inside a tag.
I want to retrieve not a new list or just text, but the *source code HTML* inside a tag. 
e.g.:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="leexample">
            justtext
            <p class="ihatelookingforfeatures">
                sometext
            </p>
            <p class="yahc">
                sometext
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="lenot">
            blabla
        </div>
    an awfuly long example for this.
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to do a method like such `hxs.select('//div[@id="leexample"]/html()')` that shall return me the HTML inside of it, like this:

```html
justtext
<p class="ihatelookingforfeatures">
    sometext
</p>
<p class="yahc">
    sometext
</p>
```

I hope I cleared the ambiguousness around my question.

How to get the HTML from an `HtmlXPathSelector` in Scrapy? (perhaps a solution outside scrapy's scope?)

Comment: What do you mean by *"retrieve all of the HTML"*? You need to show an example.

Comment: my original thought was to go recursively over all teh tags inside a tag, reproduce them as html, but that's waaay to complicated, somebody must have thought about something simpler..

Answer (score 6):

Call `.extract()` on your `XpathSelectorList`. It shall return a list of unicode strings contains the HTML content you want.

```
hxs.select('//div[@id="leexample"]/*').extract()
```

### Update

```
# This is wrong
hxs.select('//div[@id="leexample"]/html()').extract()
```

`/html()` is not a valid scrapy selector. To extract all children, use `'//div[@id="leexample"]/*'` or `'//div[@id="leexample"]/node()'`. Note that, `node()` will return `textNode`, the result kind of like:

```
[u'\n   ',
 u'<a href="image1.html">Name: My image 1 
'
]
```

Comment: /html() is not supported, i'm not even sure if its valid. Scrapy will throw: `ValueError: Invalid XPath: //h1/html()`

Answer (score 3):

**Use**:

```
//span[@class="title"]/node()
```

this selects all nodes (elements, text-nodes, processing-instructions and comments) that are children of any `span` element in the XML document whose `class` attribute has the value `"title"`.

**If you want to get only the children-nodes of the first such `span` in the document, use**:

```
(//span[@class="title"])[1]/node()
```

Comment: It's nice, but not what I asked. it returns a list of elements -> I need the HTML behind those elements. not nodes => plain HTML.

Comment: @Saga: This cannot be done with XPath -- you need within the progamming language that hosts XPath to use a particular DOM method/property (such as `OuterXML` or `InnerXml` -- or these may be named `OuterHtml` / `InnerHtml` -- or in other DOM -- `node.Save()`)

Comment: Watchout: `//span[@class="title"]/node()` will fail if there are multiple classes. Join it with css selector to select elements with given class: `parent.css('.title').xpath('node()')`

Comment: @Kangur, CSS is not needed. See this answer explaining how to determine an element has a class, that may appear with other class-names: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35354908/36305

Answer (score 1):

Though late I leave this for the record.

What I do is:

```
html = ''.join(hxs.select('//span[@class="title"]/node()').extract())
```

Or if we want to match various nodes:

```
elements = hxs.select('//span[@class="title"]')
html = [''.join(e) for e in elements.select('./node()')]
```

Answer (score 0):

similiary to what @xiaowl pointed out,
using `hxs.select('//div[@id="leexample"]').extract()` would retrieve all the HTML contents of the tag retrieven from the xPath query: `//div[@id="leexample"]`.

so for the record, I ended up with;

```
post = postItem() #body = Field #/in item.py
post['body'] = hxs.select('//span[@id="edit' + self.postid+ '"]').extract()
open('logs/test.log', 'wb').write(str(post['body']))
#logs.test.log contains all the HTML inside the tag selected by the query.
```

Comment: If xiaowl's answer was helptful, please accept/upvote his answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not that hard as it seems. Just remove the final / of your XPath query, and use the extract() method. I've ran an example in `scrapy shell`, here's a shortened version:

```
sjaak:~ sjaakt$ scrapy shell
2012-07-19 11:06:21+0200 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.14.4 started (bot: scrapybot)
>>> fetch('http://www.nu.nl')
2012-07-19 11:06:34+0200 [default] INFO: Spider opened
2012-07-19 11:06:34+0200 [default] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.nu.nl> (referer: None)
>>> hxs.select("//h1").extract()
[u'<h1>    <script type="text/javascript">document.write(NU.today())</script>.\n    Het laatste nieuws het eerst op NU.nl    </h1>\n    ']
>>>
```

To get only the inner content of a tag, use add /* to your XPath query. Example:

```
>>> hxs.select("//h1/*").extract()
[u'<script type="text/javascript">document.write(NU.today())</script>.\n    Het laatste nieuws het eerst op NU.nl    ']
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of hacking (getting into private property `_root` of `Selector`,works in 1.0.5):

```
from lxml import html
def extract_inner_html(sel):
    return (sel._root.text or '') + ''.join([html.tostring(child) for child in sel._root.iterdescendants()])

def extract_inner_text(sel):
    return (''.join(sel.css('::text').extract())).strip()
```

Use it like:

```
reason = extract_inner_html(statement.css(".politic-rating .rate-reason")[0])
text = extract_inner_text(statement.css('.politic-statement')[0])
all_text = extract_inner_text(statement.css('.politic-statement'))
```

I've found lxml code part [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123351/equivalent-to-innerhtml-when-using-lxml-html-to-parse-html).