# How to find elements with two possible class names by XPath?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

How to find elements with two possible class names using an `XPath` expression?

I'm working in Python with `Selenium` and I want to find all elements which `class` has one of two possible names.

1. class="item ng-scope highlight"
2. class="item ng-scope"

`'//div[@class="list"]/div[@class="item ng-scope highlight"]//h3/a[@class="ng-binding"]'`

Of course I can do two separate searches and concat results into one list. But there is a more simple and efficient way. Maybe by using `|`.

Comment: Good question +1. What if you have: class="ng-scope item" ? This is essentially the same as class="item ng-scope" . And for class="item ng-scope highlight" there are 6 possible permutations. Would you like a solution that will select the elements with the wanted classes regardless of the possible permutations? See my answer for a solution!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `or`:

```
//div[@class="list"]/div[@class="item ng-scope highlight" or @class="item ng-scope"]//h3/a[@class="ng-binding"]
```

Note that `ng-scope` in general is not a good class name to rely on, because it is a "pure technical" AngularJS specific class (same goes for the `ng-binding` actually) that angular elements have. Please see if using `contains()` and checking the `item` class only would be enough to cover the use case:

```
//div[@class="list"]/div[contains(@class, "item")]//h3/a[@class="ng-binding"]
```

FYI, note how concise a CSS selector could be in your case:

```
div.list > div.item h3 a
```

Comment: The second expression will match "`item`", but will also match "`myitem3`" -- which is not wanted! The first expression only finds "`item ng-scope`" or "`item ng-scope highlight`" and will not find any permutations/reorderings, or if any additional spaces are present within the value of the `class` attribute.

Comment: if it's two possible IDs instead of classes, you have to use `//*[@id="one"] | //*[@id="two"]`?

Answer (score 2):

**The accepted answer is largely incomplete**!

Its second expression will match "`item`", but will also match "`myitem3`" -- which is not wanted!

Its first expression only finds "`item ng-scope`" or "`item ng-scope highlight`" and will not match in case of any permutations/reorderings, or if any additional spaces are present within the value of the class attribute.

### **Read further for a correct solution**:

> I'm working in Python with Selenium and I want to find all elements
>   which class has one of two possible names.
>   1.class="item ng-scope highlight"
>   2.class="item ng-scope"

**I think that in addition to those two, you will also want to cover such values of the class attributes as**:

"ng-scope item"

"item highlight ng-scope"

"ng-scope item highlight"

"ng-scope highlight item"

"highlight item ng-scope"

"highlight ng-scope item"

**And, if there are variable number of spaces in each whitespace "part", or at the left or right end of the sting, you end up with an infinite number of possibilities** . . .

Another loose point is:

*Should the values of the class attribute contain exactly (only) those class-names, or are they also allowed to contain other class-names, in addition to the wanted*?

**Depending on the answer of the above question, there can be two different solutions, provided below**:

---

I. The *class* attribute can contain other class-names, besides the wanted ones:

```
/div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' list ')]
       /div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' item ') 
          and contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' ng-scope ')]
```

---

II. The *class* attribute contains exactly/only the wanted values:

```
//div[contains(normalize-space(@class) = 'list')]
       /div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' item ') 
          and contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' ng-scope ')
          and string-length(normalize-space(@class)) = 13
          or 
            contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' item ') 
            and contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' ng-scope ')
            and contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' highlight ')
            and string-length(normalize-space(@class)) = 23
          ]
```

---

**Here is a quick verification, using XSLT**. The transformation evaluates the XPath expressions and outputs the selected nodes from each expression:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
Loose classes selection:
    <xsl:copy-of select=
     "//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' list ')]
       /div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' item ') 
          and contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' ng-scope ')]
     "/>
==============================
Exact number of classes selection:
    <xsl:copy-of select=
     "//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' list ')
          and string-length(normalize-space(@class)) = 4
          ]
         /div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' item ') 
            and contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' ng-scope ')
            and string-length(normalize-space(@class)) = 13
          or 
            contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' item ') 
            and contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' ng-scope ')
            and contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' highlight ')
            and string-length(normalize-space(@class)) = 23
          ]
          "/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following document**:

```
<html>
  <div class=" list   class2 ">
    <div class ="   item ng-scope  class3  "/>
    <div class ="item   ng-scope  class4  "/>
    <div class ="item   ng-scope class5  "/>
    <div class ="item   ng-scope  highlight class6 "/>
    <div class =" highlight item  class7   ng-scope  "/>
  </div>
  <div class=" list    ">
    <div class ="   item ng-scope  "/>
    <div class ="item   ng-scope  class4  "/>
    <div class ="  ng-scope item  "/>
    <div class ="item   ng-scope  highlight  "/>
    <div class =" highligh item    ng-scope  "/>
  </div>
</html>
```

**the wanted correct results are produced in each of the two cases**:

```
Loose classes selection:
    <div class="   item ng-scope  class3  "/>
<div class="item   ng-scope  class4  "/>
<div class="item   ng-scope class5  "/>
<div class="item   ng-scope  highlight class6 "/>
<div class=" highlight item  class7   ng-scope  "/>
<div class="   item ng-scope  "/>
<div class="item   ng-scope  class4  "/>
<div class="  ng-scope item  "/>
<div class="item   ng-scope  highlight  "/>
<div class=" highligh item    ng-scope  "/>
==============================
Exact number of classes selection:
    <div class="   item ng-scope  "/>
<div class="  ng-scope item  "/>
<div class="item   ng-scope  highlight  "/>
```

---

**XPath 2.0 solutions**:

Use these two XPath 2.0 expressions:

**"Loose" expression**:

```
//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' list ')]
   /div[every $token in ('item', 'ng-scope') satisfies $token = tokenize(@class, '\s+')[.]]
```

**"Exact" expression**:

```
//div[normalize-space(@class) = 'list']
    /div[every $token in ('item', 'ng-scope') satisfies $token = tokenize(@class, '\s+')[.]
            and not(tokenize(@class, '\s+')[.][3])
          or 
            (every $token in ('item', 'ng-scope', 'highlight') 
               satisfies $token = tokenize(@class, '\s+')[.]
            and not(tokenize(@class, '\s+')[.][4]))
          ]
```

Comment: if it's two possible IDs instead of classes, you have to use `//*[@id="one"] | //*[@id="two"]`?

Comment: @Anthony, having an id attribute is quite different and actually much simpler case -- one can use the XPath id() function, if the attribute is declared as IDREF in a DTD for the XML document, or one can use XSLT keys, or in XPath 2.0 or later, one can use `//div[@id = ('one', 'two')]`

The expression provided in your comment may not be optimized by the XPath engine and will be rather inefficient. If one wants to use a similar, but more efficient to evaluate expression, then use: `//div[@id = 'one' or @id = 'two']

Comment: ahhh ok so you bracket the actual IDs. i had already tried your last expression and it wasnt working for some reason although i was using `driver.find_element(By.ID, 'xpath/here')` so is that why?

Comment: i also just tried `//*[@id = ('one', 'two')]` and its telling me the expression is not legal. i also tried `//*[@id=("priceblock_saleprice" or "priceblock_ourprice")]` and although it doesnt create any errors or exceptions the `.text` is blank??

Comment: @Anthony, The answers to your questions are simple -- you have a non-compliant to the XPath 1.0 specification XPath engine -- and it is definitely not an XPath 2.0 or later one

Comment: Sorry, but I'm confused. So the XPath is not compliant to XPath 1.0 or XPath 2.0? Or `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'xpath')` is not compliant? Or?

Comment: @Anthony, Actually, it may be a valid XPath 1.0 implementation -- I now see that you didn't use the XPath expression that I provided -- you used: `//*[@id=("priceblock_saleprice" or "priceblock_ourprice")]` but I gave you: `//div[@id = 'one' or @id = 'two']`  you haven't coded correctly the second argument of `or`. It seems that you can benefit from reading a Pluralsight course describing XPath 1.0 in detail -- I can (shamelessly) recommend my own Pluralsight course: `XSLT 2.0 and 1.0 Foundations` at https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/xslt-foundations-part1

Comment: oh whoops i mustve copied and pasted the wrong thing. i did actually try `//div[@id = 'one' or @id = 'two']` and although it doesnt create any errors or exceptions the `.text` is blank if i remember correctly??

Comment: wow `//*[@id="priceblock_saleprice"] | //*[@id="priceblock_ourprice"]` is actually 3/10ths of a second faster than `//*[@id="priceblock_saleprice" or @id="priceblock_ourprice"]` and a 1/10th of a second faster average time per lookup

Comment: @Anthony, This depends on the specific XML document and on its size and structure and on the values distribution of `@id`. Also, if the XPath engine has an intelligent optimizer, it will optimize the first expression into the second -- the time difference you see may not be significant at all. And if you get different results from the two expressions -- again, you have a non-compliant XPath implementation

Comment: Yes, I know there are tons of variable factors that come into play to determine the efficiency of selectors/searches. I don't understand what you mean by 'I have a non-compliant XPath implementation'. Are you talking about the website that I'm scraping, the Selenium framework, or what?

Comment: @Anthony, Whatevere you are using, that produces **different results** evaluating the  two XPath expressions:  `//div[@id = 'one' or @id = 'two']` and  `//div[@id="one"] | //div[@id="two"]` -- is non-XPath compliant

Comment: one or the other or both of them are non-xpath compliant?

Comment: @Antony -- No, just the software (XPath engine) you are using to evaluate these XPath expression is not XPath compliant. To put it shortly -- it is rather buggy and incomplete