# innerhtml equivalent using cssselect in lxml.html

Tags: python, html-parsing, css-selectors, lxml, innerhtml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equivalent to InnerHTML when using lxml.html to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123351/equivalent-to-innerhtml-when-using-lxml-html-to-parse-html)

What is the equivalent of innerHTLML for cssselect using lxml.html with python 2.7?

```
import lxml.html, cssselect

doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(htmldocstring)
e = doc.cssselect('div.mainl')[0]
print e.innerHTML #This doesn't work
```

How do I get the inner/outer html of e?

**Outer html**
To get the outer html you do:

```
print lxml.html.tostring(e)
```

Still don't know how to get innerHTML.

Comment: It's not necessary to edit your answer with the duplicate link once you have already voted to close your question. That said I've gone ahead and closed it for you. You can still accept your own answer when time permits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out...

```
print lxml.html.tostring(e)
```