# xpath to get only the content not the self tag

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

```
<div id="content">
   foo <br/>
   bar <br/>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the inner text of the `content` div above with the following:

```
response.xpath('//div[@id ="content"]').extract()
```

this gives me the following:

```
[u'<div id="content"> foo<br/>bar <br/></div>
```

How can I get:

```
foo<br/>bar</br>
```

Comment: What language are you using to call response.xpath and .extract()?

Comment: updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
''.join(map(methodcaller('strip'), response.xpath('//div[@id ="content"]/node()').extract()))
# output: u'foo<br>bar<br>'
```

Please note that this changes the `<br />` to `<br>` by `lxml` but if you don't need those inner tags, you could do this:

```
response.xpath('normalize-space(//div[@id ="content"])').extract_first()
# output: u'foo bar'
```

Comment: This will lose the ability to distinguish elements from text (e.g. `&lt;b&gt;`).

Answer (score 0):

lxml is impressively inconvenient in many places – getting an element’s inner HTML is one of them. Adapted from [an answer by lormus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6396097/707111):

```
from lxml import html

def inner_html(element):
    return (
        (element.text or '') +
        ''.join(html.tostring(child, encoding='unicode') for child in element)
    )
```

In use:

```
>>> from scrapy.selector import Selector
>>> response = Selector(text="""
... <div id="content">
...    foo <br/>
...    bar <br/>
... </div>
... """)
>>> inner_html(response.css('#content')[0].root)
'\n   foo <br>\n   bar <br>\n'
```