# HTMl Xpath that return with tags /mark up

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, lxml

Input Html

```
<section id="article">
  <p>Hey This is XXX</p>
</section>
```

Im using using lxml xpath to extract Data

```
xpath_paragraph = '//section[@id="article"]/p//text()'
items = mydoc.xpath(xpath_paragraph)
```

The Result i got is:

```
Hey This is XXX
```

Expected Result :

```
<p>Hey This is XXX</p>
```

The Result is understandable that i'm extracting text, i have also tried it with node(). its not working either. I need to extract the data with Tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent to InnerHTML when using lxml.html to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123351/equivalent-to-innerhtml-when-using-lxml-html-to-parse-html)

Comment: An XPath expression selects nodes in a tree. You can select element nodes  as described by @gtosto, but if you want tags, then you will need to serialize the returned element nodes back to lexical XML markup.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data='''
<section id="article">
 <p>Hey This is XXX</p>
 </section>'''

root = ET.fromstring(data)
for value in root.iter('section'):
    rank=value.find('p').text


#this is to initialize child  
for child in root:
    pass
    #print child.tag,child.attrib

print '<'+child.tag+'>'+rank+'</'+child.tag+'>'
```

output

```
<p>Hey This is XXX</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are explicitly selecting text nodes ('//section[@id="article"]/p//text()'), try the following expression

```
xpath_paragraph = '//section[@id="article"]/p'
```

that should select the p elements