# getting text length from lxml.html nodes and truncate

Tags: python, html, xml, lxml, truncate

In parse_html() I am trying to parse for the text of each element and get the len() of text in each element. I want to generate a script that parses the length of text in each element and when the cumulative text length reaches a set size parameter, it truncates the rest of the text in the document. My problem is in the child.text/tag1.text/tag2.text/tag3.text. len() doesn't seem to be working on these. Is there a way I can pull the numerical length of these text strings?

```
import sys
import imaplib
import getpass
import email
import email.header
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import re
from lxml import etree, html
from io import StringIO, BytesIO
from lxml.html.clean import clean_html, Cleaner, word_break
from lxml.etree import HTML 
from lxml.html import HtmlMixin 

EMAIL_ACCOUNT = "sample@gmai.com"
EMAIL_FOLDER = "INBOX"


def process_mailbox(M):
    """
    Do something with emails messages in the folder.  
    For the sake of this example, print some headers.
    """

    rv, data = M.search(None, "ALL")
    if rv != 'OK':
        print "No messages found!"
        return
    for num in data[0].split(): 
        rv, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        if rv != 'OK':
            print "ERROR getting message", num
            return

        msg = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
        decode = email.header.decode_header(msg['Subject'])[0]
        subject = unicode(decode[0])
        body = msg.get_payload(decode=True)
        print 'Message %s: %s' % (num, subject)
        print 'Raw Date:', msg['Date']
        print 'Body:', body

        if msg.is_multipart():
            html = None
            print "Checking for html or text"
            for part in msg.get_payload():
                if part.get_content_charset() is None:
                    charset = chardet.detect(srt(part))['encoding']
                else:
                    charset = part.get_content_charset()
                    if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
                    text = unicode(part.get_payload(decode=True),str(charset),"ignore").encode('utf8','replace')
                    f = open('email.txt', 'w')
                    f.write(text)
                    f.close
                if part.get_content_type() == 'text/html':
                    html = unicode(part.get_payload(decode=True),str(charset),"ignore").encode('utf8','replace')
                    f = open('email.html','w')
                    f.write(html)
                    f.close
                if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
                    continue

                filename = part.get_filename()

                if not os.path.isfile(filename) :
                    fp = open(filename, 'wb')
                    fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
                    fp.close()
                    return 0

            if html is None:
                return text.strip()
            else:
                return html.strip()
        # Now convert to local date-time
        date_tuple = email.utils.parsedate_tz(msg['Date'])
        if date_tuple:
            local_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
                email.utils.mktime_tz(date_tuple))
            print "Local Date:", \
                local_date.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")

def parse_html():
    #htmldoc = open('email.html', 'r+')
    #doc = htmldoc.read()
    VALID_TAGS = ['iframe', 'video', 'o>', 'li', 'sub', 'sup', 'source', 'br', 'h3', 'h4', 'h6', 'hr', 'q', 'mark','wbr', 'audio','strong', 'em', 'p','ul', 'li', 'br', 'blockquote', 'pre', 'del', 'h3', 'body', 'header', 'html', 'title', 'div', 'img', 'a']
    parser = etree.HTMLParser()
    tree = etree.parse("email.html", parser)
    #results = etree.tostring(tree.getroot(), pretty_print=True, method="html")
    page = html.tostring(tree)
    cleaner = Cleaner(page_structure=False, add_nofollow=True, style=True, links=True, safe_attrs_only=True)
    clean_page = cleaner.clean_html(page)
    root = tree.getroot()
    child = root[0]
    print len(root)
    children = list(root)
    for child in root:
        print child.tag
        print child.attrib
        print child.text
        for tag1 in child:
            print tag1.tag
            print tag1.attrib
            print tag1.text
            for tag2 in tag1:
                print tag2.tag
                print tag2.attrib
                print tag2.text
                for tag3 in tag2:
                    print tag3.tag
                    print tag3.attrib
                    print tag3.text

M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')

try:
    rv, data = M.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, getpass.getpass())
except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
    print "LOGIN FAILED!!! "
    sys.exit(1)

print rv, data

rv, mailboxes = M.list()
if rv == 'OK':
    print "Mailboxes:"
    print mailboxes

rv, data = M.select(EMAIL_FOLDER)
if rv == 'OK':
    print "Processing mailbox...\n"
    process_mailbox(M)
    parse_html()
    M.close()
else:
    print "ERROR: Unable to open mailbox ", rv

M.logout()
```

This is the error I get when I try to use len()

```
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Also, if you know anything about how to do that truncating with lxml.html, I'd appreciate being pointed in the right direction.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more efficient way to do this but I was able to get functioning results. I had to turn each child into a string and then strip the html tags of each child string. I used functions stringify_children() and strip_tags(), found at these links: [Get all text inside a tag in lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624062/get-all-text-inside-a-tag-in-lxml) and
[Strip HTML from strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python)

```
def stringify_children(node):
    from lxml.etree import tostring
    from itertools import chain
    parts = ([node.text] +
            list(chain(*([c.text, tostring(c), c.tail] for c in node.getchildren()))) +
            [node.tail])
    # filter removes possible Nones in texts and tails
    return ''.join(filter(None, parts))

    class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.fed = []
    def handle_data(self, d):
        self.fed.append(d)
    def get_data(self):
        return ''.join(self.fed)

def strip_tags(html):
    s = MLStripper()
    s.feed(html)
    return s.get_data()

tree = etree.fromstring(docstring)
walkAll = tree.iterchildren()

for elt in walkAll:
    child = stringify_children(elt)
    childtext = strip_tags(child)
    print len(childtext)
```