# How to convert XPath Element to plain html text?

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml

I have page:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <a id="123">text_url</a>
  </div>    
<body>
```

And I want to get element '//div/a' as plain html text.

```
<a id="123">text_url</a>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: from XPath point of view, `//div/a` already points to `<a id="123">text_url</a>`. The rest depends on the XPath host. What is the XPath engine you're using? programming language and the Xpath library maybe?

Comment: python language, libs - lxml, grab. As I understand, XPath standard doesn't support this common method?

Comment: I don't know python, maybe someone else can lead you the way. Usually, the XPath library provides a way to get node's markup. For example in .NET I can do something like : `var node = xml.SelectSingleNode("//div/a");
var nodesMarkup = node.OuterHtml;`

Comment: See, that isn't a matter of XPath, that's about the library API as far as I know

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4624146/821594

Comment: I'm surprised that no one has mentioned [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already parsed the object using `lxml`, you can serialize it with  `lxml.etree.tostring()`:

```
from lxml import etree
xml='''<body>
  <div>
    <a id="123">text_url</a>
  </div>    
</body>'''

root = etree.fromstring(xml)
for a in root.xpath('//div/a'):
  print etree.tostring(a, method='html', with_tail=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Working solution in python with grab module.

```
from grab import Grab

g = Grab()
g.go('file://page.htm')
print g.doc.select('//div/a')[0].html()

>><a id="123">text_url</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use re module of python with re.findall.

```
import re
print re.findall(r".*?(<a.*?<\/a>).*",x,re.DOTALL)
```

where x is
    x="""
           
              text_url
           
          
      """

```
Output:['<a id="123">text_url</a>']
```

See demo as well.

http://regex101.com/r/lF4lY6/1

Comment: regex is not proper tool for tasks where need to extract html from some tag on complex page

Answer (score 0):

You could use the xml library in Python.

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse

doc = parse('page.xml') # assuming page.xml is on disk
print doc.find('div/a[@id="123"]').text
```

Note that this would only work for strict XML.
For example, you closing body tag is incorrect and this code would fail in that case. HTML on the web is rarely strict XML.