# lxml doesn't get all text in element if text has <br />?

Tags: python, text, lxml, elementtree

I am using `lxml` to parse web document, I want to get all the text in a `<p>` element, so I use the code as follow:

```
from lxml import etree

page = etree.HTML("<html><p>test1 <br /> test2</p></html>")
print page.xpath("//p")[0].text    # this just print "test1" not "test1 <br/> test2"
```

The problem is I want to get all text in `<p>` which is `test1 <br /> test2` in the example, but `lxml` just give me `test1`.

How can I get all text in `<p>` element?

Comment: possible duplicate : [Get all text inside a tag in lxml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624062/get-all-text-inside-a-tag-in-lxml)

Comment: @har07 it seems that I should use `text_content()`, but `AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'html_content'`

Comment: okay, since you tried using `text_content()` I assumed you want the text without `<br>`. Check my answer for some possible ways

Comment: "*I want to get all text in `<p>` which is `test1 <br /> test2`*". This is not correct. The actual text content is `test1  test2`. The `<br />` element is a child of `<p>`, but it is not text.

Answer (score 2):

Several other possible ways :

```
p = page.xpath("//p")[0]
print etree.tostring(p, method="text")
```

or using XPath `string()` function (notice that XPath position index starts from 1 instead of 0) :

```
page.xpath("string(//p[1])")
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this

```
from lxml import etree

pag = etree.HTML("<html><p>test1 <br /> test2</p></html>")
# get all texts
print(pag.xpath("//p/text()"))
```

> ['test1 ', ' test2']

```
# concate
print("".join(pag.xpath("//p/text()")))
```

> test1  test2