# Extracing song length and size from HTML using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a simple mp3 down-loader from a Website. In doing so I stuck while parsing time and size of audio:

```
<div class="mp3-info">
    1.69 mins
<br/>
    2.33 mb
</div>
```

Now I need to parse `1.69 mins` and `2.33 mb` from above HTML. I am using python 3.4

Comment: What do you mean by "parse" exactly?

Comment: @skyline75489 to get the value of time and size

Comment: Are answers below meeting your needs?

Comment: @skyline75489 Not at all but I got the answer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [BeautifulSoup4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse your HTML. See docs [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

```
import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(your_html_string)
soup.findAll("div", {"class": "mp3-info"})
# Now extract the text
```

Also because it's a class, it could be that there are multiple ones on the page...

Answer (score 0):

You can extract text from HTML using [lxml](http://lxml.de/) library.

Here is related StackOverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/a/4624146/315168

After you get the length and size as text out, then you split them pieces. E.g.

```
 text = ... extract element text using lxml
 minutes, min_suffix, megabytes, mega_suffix = text.split()

 seconds = float(minutes) * 60.0
```