# Get the entire parent tag's text in ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

While using `xml.etree.ElementTree as ET` python package, I would like to get the entire text within an XML tag, which contains some child nodes. Consider the following xml:

```
<p>This is the start of parent tag...
        <ref type="chlid1">child 1</ref>. blah1 blah1 blah1 <ref type="chlid2">child2</ref> blah2 blah2 blah2 
</p>
```

Assuming that the above XML is in `node`, then `node.text` would just give me `This is the start of parent tag...`. However, I want to capture all of the text inside `p` tag (along with its child tag's texts) which would result in: `This is the start of parent tag... child 1. blah1 blah1 blah1 child2 blah2 blah2 blah2`.

Is there any work-around for this issue? I looked into the documentation but couldn't really find something that works out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a very awkward peculiarity of ElementTree. The gist is: if an element contains both text and child elements, and if a child element intervenes between different intermediate text nodes, the text after the child element is said to be this element's `tail` instead of its `text`.

In order to collect all text that is an immediate child or descendant of an element, you would need to access the `text` and `tail` of this element, and of all descendant elements.

```
>>> from lxml import etree

>>> s = '<p>This is the start of parent tag...<ref type="chlid1">child 1</ref>. blah1 blah1 blah1 <ref type="chlid2">child2</ref> blah2 blah2 blah2 </p>'

>>> root = etree.fromstring(s)
>>> child1, child2 = root.getchildren()

>>> root.text
'This is the start of parent tag...'

>>> child1.text, child1.tail
('child 1', '. blah1 blah1 blah1 ')

>>> child2.text, child2.tail
('child2', ' blah2 blah2 blah2 ')
```

As for a complete solution, I discovered that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4624146/1987598) is doing something very similar, that you can easily adapt to your usecase (by not printing the name of elements).

---

**Edit**: actually, the simplest solution by far, in my opinion, is [to use itertext](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15074386/1987598):

```
>>> ''.join(root.itertext())
'This is the start of parent tag...child 1. blah1 blah1 blah1 child2 blah2 blah2 blah2 '
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something similar with ElementTree:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
data = """[your string above]"""
tree = ET.fromstring(data)
print(' '.join(tree.itertext()).strip())
```

Output:

```
This is the start of parent tag...
         child 1 . blah1 blah1 blah1  child2  blah2 blah2 blah2
```

Comment: Right, I did not even see this was about `xml.etree` :-). +1!